# IBM Content Navigator plugin : logging using Log4J

Tags: log4j, filenet-p8, filenet, ibm-content-navigator

Hi all IBM ICN Developers,

I am working on writing an ICN plugin. I want my logger statements to get logged into a separate file rather than going in System.Out file. Has anyone configured the custom logging by using Log4J libraries in an ICN Plugin? I tried configuring exactly as we do in a Java program but the log file is not getting generated in the configured directory. Here is my log4j.properties file

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/tmp/MyPlugin.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I tried placing the log4j.properties file inside /src folder and even directly under / folder.

Can someone please help me with some pointers?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ICN are you developing on. I think(!) starting 3.0.9 IBM removed log4j in favor of JUL (Java Utility Logging).

Hope this helps.

Comment: We are using 3.0.9... we can still have Log4J2 libraries in shared lib folder and use them in our loggers. If not Log4J, how to have separate log files for logging plugin specific logs? It is not a good idea to flood SysOUT logs with everything. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Created a separate class for initializing logger instance. The init method is called from the code which gets called in the beginning of the plugin execution.

```
public class LoggingUtil {
    private static LoggingUtil instance = null;
    private static RollingFileAppender rfa = null;
    
    protected LoggingUtil() {
        
    }
    
    public static LoggingUtil getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new LoggingUtil();
          }
          return instance;
    }
    
    public void init() {

        if (rfa == null) {

            try{
                LoggerContext context  = (LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext(false);
                File file = new File("//opt//log4j.xml");
                
                context.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
                System.out.println("Log4J properties configured...");
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("ERROR occurred while loading properties file");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```